# How to understand the difference between solutions of 2nd-order ODE using Laplace Transform and Reduction of Order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, reduction-of-order-ode

## Problem Statement

So here is the problem.

> Solve
> $$
> xy'' + 2y' = 4x^3
> $$

Note there is no boundary conditions provided here though.

The textbook provided a solution using reduction of order (which is attached below), but I tried to solve it with Laplace Transform, which gives a slightly different form. Basically, the two solutions are,

From *reduction of order*, $y=\frac{1}{5}x^4 -\frac{C_1}{x} + C_2$

From *Laplace Transform*, $y=\frac{1}{5}x^4 + C_1\delta(x)+C_2$

So you see, the **second terms** are different from two solutions. One gives a inverse proportion as $\frac{1}{x}$, while the other is a *delta function*.

They look similar (i can sort of perceive) but are both solutions correct? If so, how could I consolidate the two solutions? I am hoping to get more understanding into the two methods. Thanks!

The detailed solution steps are attached below.

## Attached Detailed Solutions

### Reduction of order

Let $u=y'$, so that,
$$
x\frac{du}{dx} + 2u = 4x^3
$$
Multiplying by x,
$$
x^2\frac{du}{dx} + 2xu = 4x^4\\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^2u) = 4x^4
$$
This can be integrated to give
$$
u = \frac{4}{5}x^3 + \frac{C_1}{x^2}
$$
from which,
$$
y = \frac{1}{5}x^4 - \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2
$$
for $x\neq0$

### Laplace Transform

First apply Laplace transform to all terms,
$$
\mathcal{L}(xy'') = -2sY - s^2Y' + y(0)\\
\mathcal{L}(y') = sY - y(0)\\
\mathcal{L}(x^3) = \frac{3!}{s^4}
$$
Putting everything into the ODE and organize, we have,
$$
Y' = -24s^{-6} - y(0)s^{-2}\\
Y = \frac{24}{5}s^{-5} + y(0)s^{-1} + C
$$
Apply inverse Laplace transform, we can get,
$$
y = \frac{1}{5}x^4 + y(0) + C\delta(t)
$$
Rename constants to a comparable form, we have finally
$$
y = \frac{1}{5}x^4 + C_1\delta(t) + C_2
$$
For this case, $x>=0$.

Comment: The reduction of order gives a solution which is a smooth function. Laplace transform will give a solution which is a distribution supported on the positive semiaxis. And here is the problem: $1/x$ is not a distribution, just as $\delta$ is not a function. Both solutions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

This answer has nothing to do with your question, but provides another way to solve the problem.

\begin{align*}
xy^{\prime\prime} + 2y^{\prime} = 4x^{3} \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y^{\prime\prime} + 2xy^{\prime} = 4x^{4} \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y^{\prime})^{\prime} = 4x^{4} \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y^{\prime} = \frac{4x^{5}}{5} + k
\end{align*}